# USB GPS receiver compatible with Raspberry Pi

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a USB GPS receiver for turning a Raspberry Pi into a GPS navigation system.

Requirements:

- Thumb-drive-like form factor
- Compatibility with [GPSD](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/)
- Low power (*shouldn't* be a problem with any receiver, but the Pi is somewhat touchy about USB devices drawing too much power).
- Price: less than $50

Nice to have:

- Support for satellite networks other than the US GPS system.
- Support for various accuracy-augmentation systems.
- Magnetic compass.

Answer (score 2):

**The [Globalsat ND100](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Globalsat-ND100-upgrade-ND105C-ND-105C-Super-Small-GPS-USB-Dongle-New-2015-/221454923733) seems to be what you're looking for.**

It's a bit bulky, but it seems to do everything you need it to do.

- It's only $35USD
- Has a thumb-drive-like form factor (Besides it being a bit bulkier than a thumb-drive)
- It states to have `"Very low power consumption"`
- According to [this](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/hardware.html) article, any GPS  receiver that advertises NMEA-0183 compliance will work with GPSD; which this receiver does. So it should be compatible (Though I never tested it)

**Edit:**
Looks like this actually uses Micro-USB, not standard USB. But a simple [adapter](http://www.amazon.ca/Male-Micro-Female-Adapter-Black/dp/B009AWA3VK/ref=pd_cp_229_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1M96GTNNN4XWX6PY11HY) should work (And still be well under your budget)

Comment: I think the correct adapter would be a "Micro B female to A male", and with the adapter (of whatever sort), the ND100 would be sticking out far enough that I'm worried it would break off or catch on something and get unplugged.

Comment: Ah, yes; My mistake, that's the adapter I meant. I updated the link (Unless I got it wrong again, that'd be awkward..) I get what you mean by it might be too long, but from what I saw, this is the closest there was that was a thumb-drive form factor. Hopefully someone else can provide a better option that suits your needs..